# Compile C++ 11 with clang 3.4 and GraphicsMagick

Tags: software-installation, compiling, c++, clang

I wanna to compile C++ code in this source https://github.com/jdeng/rbm-mnist I have installed clang 3.4, `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` , and `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`.

I found that there isn't `/usr/include/GraphicsMagick` and `Magick++.h` locates in `/usr/include/ImageMagick`.

I have run this command `clang++ --std=c++0x -o dbn -g -O2 demo.cc -lz -I /usr/include/ImageMagick -lGraphicsMagick++` but an error occurred, it is  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGraphicsMagick++`

I have no idea because I already installed `libmagickwand-dev`, could you please help?

Comment: The files that you are looking for appear to be in package `libgraphicsmagick++1-dev` not `libmagickwand-dev`. See [the libgraphicsmagick++1-dev filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgraphicsmagick++1-dev/filelist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++1-dev` instead of `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

The library you need is located in the `libgraphicsmagick++3` package (on release *14.10*). You can use the package search feature of the ubuntu website to search for it.

Once installed, you may use `dpkg` or `ldconfig` to locate the library in the file system:

```
$ dpkg -S 'libGraphicsMagick++.so'

 libgraphicsmagick++3: /usr/lin/LibgraphicsMagick++.so.3

$ ldconfig -p | grep Graph
    LibgGraphicsMagick++.so.3 (libc6.x86-64) => /usr/lib/llibGraphicsMagick++.so.3
```